# Beautiful soup not importing everything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On windows and using BS4 on Jupiter notebook. I am trying to build a shitcoin tracker to show some properties on a web crawler just for fun. Here is the website I am using to **scrape** from:
https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf

I would like to get the circled portion number in to my webcrawler in to beautiful soup:
[image: website]

Here is the code I used to look for this part on html through "inspect" function on the website and trying to load it into beautiful soup and nothing seems to be working. Picture below:

[image]

And here is the code I used at my noob attempt:

```
SHITCOIN = "snek"
tokensuffix = '0xef2ec90e0b8d4cdfdb090989ea1bc663f0d680bf'
poocoin_url = 'https://poocoin.app/tokens' + tokensuffix
poocoin_request = requests.get(poocoin_url, {'headers':headers})
soupoo = bs4.BeautifulSoup(poocoin_request.content,'html.parser')
poocoin_number = soupoo.find_all("div",{"class":"text-success"})
print(poocoin_number)
```

and the output I get is just an empty list.

Am I misusing the syntax or is it the parser? Apologies for noob question first time building a **webscraper** using beautiful soup.

Comment: `span` is not a `div` so why is your query on `div` ?

Comment: @Andy I tried also with span but it did not work so I tried with div.

Comment: That's because this info is loaded dynamically. You can use a [dynamic parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795799/how-to-scrape-dynamic-webpages-by-python) for this.